# Simple Hello World app

Tags: java, android

When I try running this code it says "Error:not an enclosing class:MainActivity" and "Error:Missing method body or declare abstract." And there's probably a really simple answer for this but I am new to Android and Java programming, so sorry for my noob-ishness.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v);
    });
}


//Activities
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("TaskActivity", "MainActivity Started");
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("TaskActivity", "MainActivity Resumed");
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("TaskActivity", "MainActivity Paused");
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("TaskActivity", "MainActivity Stopped");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("TaskActivity", "MainActivity Destroyed");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the entire class, sounds like you have a brace in the wrong spot somewhere.

Comment: try `this` instead of `MainActivity.this`. Post more code if it wont work. Especially activity class.

Comment: I see your edit. Now please tell me what are you trying to achieve via this Intent lines. I almost certain that this code should be in other place

Comment: i am trying to make it so that when i prss a button the already displayed text "Goodbye World" will change via Activity to "Hello world" and also be able to go back and forth between activities

Comment: looking at your question and code, it seems to me like you have very little knowledge about programming, and copy&pasted some code and try to make it do what you want. you should probably consider first learning some more basic stuff (specifically about java), probably by following tutorials or maybe even doing some basic course/book about programming (in java). trying to go directly to what you want to do may not actually be the fastest way to get there, and might be just the recipe for an endless road of frustration ahead of you.

Comment: @hoijui Well I didn't actually copy and paste and I said I was new to Android and Java programming.

Comment: i am sorry, i see now that my first sentence sounded like an insult/accusation, but i did not mean that. of course it is no shame to not know something, everyone did not know anything at one time. i just wanted to say what i think would be best for you, in the long run.

Comment: @hoijui oh I'm sorry. And thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the onClick Method

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of your `Intent()` should be the current (enclosing) class. The second argument is the `Activity` to load. Check the [Developer Docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))

If you want to launch `MainActivity` from `MainActivity2`, reverse the arguments so your `Intent` looks like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The error relating to your method likely comes from using the incorrect syntax when assigning your `onClickListener`. If you are trying to start `MainActivity` from a button press, you will need to re-write this section:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but there is still the "Missing method body, or declare abstract" error.

Comment: @EliasE That's probably caused by incorrect syntax in your `onClick`. Take a look at my edit for one solution.